# android how to get google API key for google places?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Hi I am working with google places API. But it causes error

URL:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=2500,25000&radius=5000&types=a&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAt8zjW45u7rjH1la48kfvZNZ1nDpbCOAM

Error:

{    "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",    "html_attributions" : [],    "results" : [],    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed something related to API_KEY generating and using. Please re-check if you have generated API_KEY properly for your package name. You can refer steps at : [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/)